# How to repeat a user input email if not valid

Tags: c++

So I am trying to use a loop in the email setter where if it isn't valid it should repeat the user input email prompt. The thing is, if I type in a valid email at first it will break the loop which is what I want but if I type in an invalid email first it will repeat the loop twice and then if I type in a valid email after that it will still repeat the loop and I'm just stuck in an infinite loop. I know I'm probably doing something stupid but I can't seem to get it working.

User.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "User.h"

//Email regex
std::string userEmailRegex = ".+@.+";

//Validates data against a user-defined string
bool validate(std::string regexStr, std::string data)
{
    return std::regex_match(data, std::regex(regexStr));
}

User::User()
{
}

User::User(std::string email, std::string password, std::string username)
{
    setEmail(email);
    setPassword(password);
    setUsername(username);
}

User::~User()
{
}

void User::setEmail(std::string email)
{
    bool bValid = validate(userEmailRegex, email);
    for (;;)
    {
        if (bValid)
        {
            this->email = email;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Please enter a valid email adress!\n";
            std::cout << "Email: ";
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(512, '\n');
        }
    }

}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "User.h"
#include "DkDateTime.h"

User u;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Welcome to MySocialNetwork!\n"; 
std::cout << "Please Login below:\n";
std::cout << std::endl;

std::vector<User> v;

std::string email;
std::cout << "Email: ";
std::cin >> email;
u.setEmail(email);
std::cout << u.getEmail() << std::endl;
std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Move `validate()` function into `User` class. Remove loops from `setEmail()` function and move it into main. Try to read an email address from the user input until it's valid. Something like: `do { std::cin >> email; } while (!u.validate(email));`

Comment: It coming up as 'too few arguments in function call' at the while loop now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've misplaced your validation code, and inside your setEmail code you never stored the email that the user input

```
void User::setEmail(std::string email)
{
    for (;;)
    {
        bool bValid = validate(userEmailRegex, email);
        if (bValid)
        {
            this->email = email;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Please enter a valid email adress!\n";
            std::cout << "Email: ";
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(512, '\n');
            std::cin >> email;
        }
    }

}
```

so if you move `bool bValid = validate(userEmailRegex, email);` into the loop instead, you should get the expected result.

OBS: not tested but should get you toward the correct validation

Comment: I knew it was something so small, works perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You receive an email address as a parameter to a setter method, fine. But then, if it is not valid, you loop asking a new string from stdin, *inside the setter method* which is at least a questionable design. It will prevent to use that class in a batch context or in a service getting its input from HTTP messages or anything else not tightly bound to a terminal.

For the sake of separation of concerns, the loop should be outside of the user class: it is a UI concern, not user management. IMHO you should make `validate` a `User` class static method and move the loop into the `main` function:

```
//Validates data against a user-defined string
static bool User::validate(std::string data)
{
    //Email regex
    static std::string userEmailRegex = ".+@.+";

    return std::regex_match(data, std::regex(User::regexStr));
}

void User::setEmail(std::string email, bool validated = false)
{
    if (! (validated || validate(userEmailRegex, email))) {
        raise std::invalid_argument("Invalid email");
    }
    this->email = email;
}

int main()
{
    ...
    for (;;) {

        std::cout << "Email: ";
        std::cin >> email;
        if (User::validate(email)) {
            u.setEmail(email);
            break;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Please enter a valid email adress!\n";
        }
    }
    std::cout << u.getEmail() << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```